# Android Studio 3.5.2 – Image Asset Launcher Icon Transparent Background Color

Tags: android, android-studio

I set shape to "none", but the background is not transparent. 
Why is this happening?

I just upgraded my Android Studio version to 3.5.2. 
Before this version, it worked fine.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The same issue has been reported both on [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57721290/android-studio-3-5-image-asset-launcher-icon-legacy-only-shape-none-not-workin) and [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140183584). Turns out this is intended behavior so it will not be fixed with an update of Android Studio.

You can though follow [Abbas m's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58465031/10254610) to manually create a transparent background drawable resource and use it as the background layer with "Launcher Icons (Adaptive and Legacy)" Icon Type.